# How do I configure DMVPN for two sites?

Tags: cisco, routing, vpn, tunnel

Both ends are using a broadband connection. How do I set up DMVPN with dyndns on both ends;

I have dyndns.org account.

I don't have any static IP address.

The master router is a 3921, and the other end is a 2911.

Comment: At least one side must have a static IP address.

Comment: There is no way to connect like this scenario?

Comment: The hub router must have a static IP address. Spoke routers can have dynamic IP addresses.

Comment: There's theoretically nothing stopping you from using the DHCP assigned address for the hub.  You'll just have an outage and need to somehow reconfigure all spokes when the address changes.  Since that's not acceptable in 99% of deployment scenarios, that's why you want a static IP on the hub.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits of DMVPN is that you could create a dynamic full mesh network without having to worry about end-points (static configuration of end-points peers). 
VPN headends (the hubs) must be statically configured on the spokes (this is why you need a static IP).

summing: DMVPN let you have to configure the hub ones, drammatically reducing the deployment complexity in VPNs and not need to modify the configuration to accept a new spoke but the head of your VPNs must be static.

in addition, to better understand the world of DMVPN I suggest to you to read the official CISCO documentation about this topic, which discusses in detail each deployment scenario and the structure itself of DMVPN .

I leave a link if it can be useful to the reader :
*http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/security/dynamic-multipoint-vpn-dmvpn/DMVPN_Overview.pdf*

Answer (score 0):

You could get a Linux instance at a cloud provider such as Amazon that does have a static IP address on it and use it as your hub and run OpenNHRP on the instance.